# Is it possible to overlay SwiftUI Views onto other applications running on my computer?

Tags: swift, macos

**Motivation**
I am trying to build a menu-bar application that turns text into emojis, similar to how discord does it (images below for reference)

[This is how the text normally appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc7F4.png)

[When I want to add in an emoji, I can type the emoji name between colons to have it get auto-inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkhZe.png)

**Problem**
I am wondering if it is even possible to create a popup that appears above the cursor location in other applications. Additionally, if that is possible, is it possible to edit the text in those applications?

I have created an application with the Accessibility API that tells me where the cursor is in a selected textbox, but I have not been able to make progress on getting a popup bar to appear over that textbox.

I have tried googling to see if anyone else has ran across this problem, and I haven't seen any problems that seem to match my own.

Thanks so much for the help in advance!

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to create general popup, that will show whenever text is entered in whatever app? That should not be possible.

Comment: Isn't a popup a window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Rocket](https://matthewpalmer.net/rocket/) app that does exactly what you describe. So the answer on your question - yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s possible using the Accessibility API. You would need to create a floating widget kind of view and interrogate the frontmost app/window and then get the position of said external app. The widget needs the proper Accessibility permissions.